# Get table from web page

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to get table from web page using Selenium webdriver. First I am logging in to webpage, then proceeding to web page with table.

The problem is that table does not have `td` tags and web page source code looks like:

[image]

C# code:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Table_Scrape
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://website.com/login");
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("username")).SendKeys("MYusername");
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("password")).SendKeys("MYpassword");
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("btnSubmit_6")).Click();

            driver.FindElement(By.Id("btnContinue")).Click();

            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://website.com/table");

            IList<IWebElement> allElement = driver.FindElements(By.TagName("td"));
            foreach (IWebElement element in allElement)
            {
                string cellText = element.Text;
                Console.WriteLine(cellText);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to get data out of webpage?

Table structure is the same for each row. Columns are like `slick-cell 10 r0`, `slick-cell 10 r1` etc.

---

**EDIT:**

Console output:

```
DevTools listening on ws://xxxx:xxx/devtools/browser/0a02f6b7-3c33-41ea-b0b3-fb67d3f436c7
[1583946337.939][WARNING]: Timed out connecting to Chrome, retrying...
[1583946340.587][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
[1583946343.800][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
[1583946343.903][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
[1583946344.024][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
[1583946345.482][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
[1583946345.583][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
[1583946347.170][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
```

Comment: Try finding the elements by class, ie: `slick-cell`.

Comment: Should it search for partial match somehow? `driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[contains(text(),'slick-cell')]"));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `IList<IWebElement> allElement = driver.FindElements(By.TagName("td"));` I would use
`IList<IWebElement> allElement = driver.FindElements(By.Xapth("//div[contains(@class,'slick-cell')]"));`
However if this class name is not unique then different approach would be needed. If that's the case. let me know and we probably will need to do it via `parent div>child div` depending open which table you want to iterate.

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through all the elements that have the "slick-cell" class.
Here is a link to the code to do that:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31606955/10880378